# Debian Linux (jessie) booting up read only

Tags: debian, boot, readonly

I  recently installed Debian Linux (Jessie ). Now the system has crashed - see below.

```
Debian GNU/Linux 8 user ty1
user login: [   72.811767] EXT4-FS error (device sda1): ext4_journal_check_start:56: Detected aborted journal
[   72.812083] EXT4-FS error (device sda1): ext4_journal_check_start:56: Detected aborted journal 
sudo touch 'forcefsck
```

Answer (score 1):

Reboot and Debian should automatically check the disk for errors and repair them.

If it does not (unlikely) and the error repeats on next boot, while in GRUB boot loader, edit kernel command line (with **e**) and add `forcefsck` at the end of the line ending with `quiet`